# getting error NameError: name 'main_screen' is not defined for a tkinter login system

Tags: python, authentication, tkinter, nameerror

i keep getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/computing project/test2.py", line 21, in <module>
    main_screen.mainloop() # start the GUI
NameError: name 'main_screen' is not defined
```

while trying to create a simple tkinter login system i have tried changing the main_screen.mainloop to TK.mainloop

```
from tkinter import*


def main_account_screen():

    main_screen = Tk()   # create a GUI window 
    main_screen.geometry("1920x1080") # set the configuration of GUI window 
    main_screen.title("Account Login") # set the title of GUI window

# create a Form label 
Label(text="Choose Login Or Register", bg="blue", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack() 
Label(text="").pack() 

# create Login Button 
Button(text="Login", height="2", width="30").pack() 
Label(text="").pack() 

# create a register button
Button(text="Register", height="2", width="30").pack()

main_screen.mainloop() # start the GUI

main_account_screen() # call the main_account_screen() function
```

Comment: You're using `main_screen` outside of the scope of `main_account_screen`

Comment: In short - you need to indent everything from `Label(text=...)` to `main_screen.mainloop()` to the same level of your `main_account_screen` function. Then you can properly call the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this snippet of code if you want no errors

```
from tkinter import *

main_screen = Tk()  # create a GUI window


def main_account_screen():
    global main_screen
    main_screen.geometry("1920x1080")  # set the configuration of GUI window
    main_screen.title("Account Login")  # set the title of GUI window


# create a Form label
Label(text="Choose Login Or Register", bg="blue", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
Label(text="").pack()

# create Login Button
Button(text="Login", height="2", width="30").pack()
Label(text="").pack()

# create a register button
Button(text="Register", height="2", width="30").pack()

main_screen.mainloop()  # start the GUI

main_account_screen()  # call the main_account_screen() function
```

This will perfectly work as you have used the `global` keyword